# Get Initial URL on Angular App initialisation

Tags: angular, url

I am writing an angular application for a landing page for a SaaS application. The SaaS is redirecting to the angular application with the URL `http://localhost:4200/token=<token>` and angular quickly changes to the home component `http://localhost:4200/#/`.

I need to get the value of `<token>` to use in the code. How do I copy the initial URL in an angular application?

Comment: Is there no ? in http://localhost:4200/token=<token>?

Comment: @MikeOne, the url changes very quickly. I want to grab ```<token>``` as soon as the page opens.

Comment: I understand. But that given url doesn’t seem valid in the first place

Comment: https://contoso.com/signup?token=<token><authorization_token> that is the form that microsoft gives it

Comment: So there is a ? In there after all. Good. I think your issue might be that you are using a hashLocationStrategy.. otherwise it shouldn’t be a problem to get that from the activatedRoute inside app.component..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In your AppRoutingModule:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
 
const routes:Routes = [
  {
    path:'',
    component: MainComponent, // Your main component, wich is going to get the token
    pathMatch: ‘full’
  },
  {
    path:'/:token',
    component: MainComponent, // Your main component, wich is going to get the token
  },
... // Your others routes:
  {
    path:'xxx',
    component: XxxComponent 
  },
  {
    path:'**',
    redirectTo: ''
  }
 
]

NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

2. Remember to import in your AppModule your AppRoutingModule:

```
...
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
...
 imports: [
    ...
    AppRoutingModule,
    ...
  ],
```

3. In your MainComponent, wich is going to get the token

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

  token:  string

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.token = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('token');

    // If you were to receive countinuosly tokens :
    // this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe( _token => this.token = _token);}
```

```
Finally, you only have to call angular like this:
**http://localhost:4200/token**
```

Comment: this is not a correct answer you are trying to wild card the route token - in fact he should just create a token route - which is the way its concatenated.  token=<token>.  route params are the right way but your routing is not.  you should never try and traverse the root route with a wild card, this is bad practice.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the **angular router** to get the token if its formatted as you have depicted.

import angular router from @angular/router.

```
constructor(router:Router){}
yourRoute ?:string;
ngOnInit(){
this.yourRoute = this.router.url.split('/').pop();
}
```

for future reference:

https://angular.io/api/router

if this doesn't work you can use the activated route library.

let me know.

Comment: I have tried router. I am getting an empty token because it is looking at ```http://localhost:4200/#/``` and not ```http://localhost:4200/token=<token>```. The conversion is very quick. I would have to catch the token before the app routing module moves it.

Comment: Can I use the wildcard path somehow or maybe direct me to the activated route library?

Comment: you can use route parameters in that case which is probably a better option all the way around.

Comment: also fix your routing and stop using hash.  your router should know of the route token - and you have it pointing to http://localhost:4200/#/token.

try using route parameters this will fix your issue I think. https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute